# Are there any IEEE 802.11s wireless adapters in the market?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

It's been more than one year since the IEEE 802.11s amendment has been released for mesh networking, however none of the existing wireless adapters in the market or Wi-Fi.org include the logo and support this functionality. Does anyone know the reason and when it will come to the real world?

Comment: Is this standard even past a preliminary draft I am only aware of 802.11ac and 802.11ad in the pipeline for products

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, as he stated, it's been more than a year since the 802.11s-2011 amendment to 802.11 was ratified. It is now incorporated into 802.11-2012. I believe usable drafts of 802.11s have been around since long before that.

Comment: @Spiff - I missed that I apologize.  It does not appear to have been adopted by device makers at this time.